# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED - PHP e Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, get, https

O script abaixo funciona perfeitamente quando meu site está sem SSL, ou seja, com o dominio http://www.dominio.com.br, mas quando eu ativo o SSL para o site ficar como https://www.dominio.com.br, o Google Chrome apresenta o erro "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" quando tento passar mais de 5780 caracteres via a URL.

Estou pensando em fazer o seguinte:
Pegar todos os valores armazenar em uma unica variavel array, e depois extrair eles na proxima pagina.
Mas não sei fazer isso, alguem pode ajudar por favor?

```
<?php

function redirecionaVariaveisCF7() {
?>
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '4' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
        for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
            if ( 'nome' == inputs[i].name ) {
                var nome = inputs[i].value;
            }
            if ( 'email' == inputs[i].name ) {
                var email = inputs[i].value;
            }
        }
        window.location.href = 'testes/wp_01/teste-sucesso/?nome='+nome+'&email='+email;
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirecionaVariaveisCF7' );

add_action( 'the_content', 'exibeVariaveisCF7' );

function exibeVariaveisCF7($cf7_exibe_mensagem_conteudo) {

    if(is_page('teste-sucesso')){
        $nome = htmlspecialchars($_GET["nome"]);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_GET["email"]);

        ?><script>
function cont(){
   var conteudo = document.getElementById('boxImpressaoDisponivel').innerHTML;
   tela_impressao = window.open('https://www.meudominio.com.br');
   tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
   tela_impressao.window.print();
   tela_impressao.window.close();
}
</script><?php

        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt = "<div class='container' id='boxImpressaoDisponivel'> <br> <center><img src='https://www.meudominio.com.br/testes/wp_01/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/logo.png' width='120'></center> <br><br><br>";

        if ($nome != NULL){
            $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<b>Nome:</b> " . $nome  ."<br>";
        }

        if ($email != NULL){
            $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<b>E-mail:</b> " . $email  ."<br>";
        }

        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "</div>";

        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<div class='container'>";        
        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "<input type='button' onclick='cont();' value='Imprimir'>";
        $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt .= "</div>";

    }

    $cf7_exibe_mensagem_resultado = $cf7_exibe_mensagem_txt . $cf7_exibe_mensagem_conteudo;

    return $cf7_exibe_mensagem_resultado;

}
```

Comment: Se você vai passar muitas variáveis recomendo que use POST ao invés de passar por URI, se quiser manter valores das suas variáveis do javascript entre o carregamento de pagais pode usar a localStorage.

Comment: Também pensei em usar POST o problema que por padrão esse código envia como GET não sei onde eu altero o método dele para enviar como POST

Comment: Acho que isso de localStorage pode ajudar, mas não estou conseguindo adaptar o código para acrescentar isso, você sabe me informar quais partes do código devo mudar para localStorage.setItem e localStorage.getItem por favor

Comment: Para alterar o método de envio das variáveis vá no seu formulário de envio no form action coloque método POST, mas parece que você esta fazendo isso manualmente aqui window.location.href passando por /?var=value. Na verdade seu código esta bem bagunçado misturando html, js e php, sugiro que você refaça-o para não acabar dando problemas como o tempo. Sugiro que você crie uma pagina formulário e crie outra para processar sua requisição. Se quiser que um bom de impressão apareça ao clicar no botão de enviar o formulário sugiro usar Ajax | View<=>Controll.